# Mysql add column from different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
| USER |
| _id  | - int id PK
| id   | - String id
| name |

| SUBSCRIBE |
|   user    |
| subscribe |
```

and I want to extract this data:

```
| _id | id | name | subscribe
```

Simple example

```
| USER |
|  1   | 10212551 | Mike
|  2   | 21022145 | Nick

| SUBSCRIBE |
|    1      |     2


get_info($user, $sub );

| EXPECTED RESULT |
|     $user       |  id  |  name  |  0 or 1 (false or true, if $sub has subscribed to $user)
```

My best try was with count():

```
SELECT u._id,u.id,u.name,u.email,u.country,count(s.subscribe) AS subscribe 
FROM user u,subscribe s 
WHERE u._id='$user' AND s.subscribe='$user' AND s.user='$sub'
```

But this works only if there's any record in subscribe table. So for

**get_info(2,1)**

it will give right result but for:

**get_info(1,2)**

there's nothing :/

Can somebody please help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left join in order to return user even if he has not subscribed and use case to check for subscribed

```
select u._id,u.id,u.name,u.email,u.country,
case when s.subscribe is not null then 1 else 0 end as subscribe 
from user u 
left join subscribe s on (u._id = s.user and s.subscribe ='$sub')
where u._id='$user'
```

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bab0/4)

Comment: @MichalHeneš yup there was a typo missing end for case statement try it now

Comment: That code gives me always subscribe 0 even if there's a record

Comment: @MichalHeneš see my updated answer with [`sample demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bab0/4)

Comment: Yay, yes, your code works, but I must retype **u._id = s.user and s.subscribe ='$sub'** with **u._id = s.subscribe and s.user ='$sub'**
thanks, my bad for not explained it properly :) ty